# Planned maintenance scheduled for Thursday, September 2 at 12:00am UTC (Wednesday September 1 8:00 PM US/EDT)

Tags: discussion, announcements, maintenance, downtime

> **Update: The maintenance went as planned.**

---

**tl;dr;** Planned service interruption that will impact all Stack Overflow/Stack Exchange sites, Jobs, Chat, and Teams. All sites may be read-only for up to 30 minutes on Thursday, September 2, 2021 at 12:00am UTC (Wednesday September 1 8PM US/EDT). Enterprise cloud hosted instances will not be impacted.

### Short Version:

There will be a service degradation for up to 30 minutes [12:00am UTC](https://www.worldtimebuddy.com/?qm=1&lid=100,5128581&h=100&date=2021-9-2&sln=0-1&hf=1) (midnight) on September 2, 2021 (Wednesday September 1st 8:00 PM US/EDT). During that time questions and answers will still display, job listings will still work, and job ads will still display. **However, the site will be "read only," i.e. people won't be able to add/edit new job listings, apply for jobs, post, edit or vote on questions/comments/answers, reputation won't change, etc.** This should minimize the disruption to the majority of casual readers. We will display a banner on the sites stating we're 'read only' for maintenance.

### Longer Version of What's Taking Place?

#### Background

Our primary database servers, which power Stack Overflow, Stack Exchange, Chat, and other things, run out of New York (really New Jersey) with our secondary location in Colorado. When we need to perform maintenance on the primary servers, we need to failover to another server so we can patch, upgrade, and reboot them.

#### What we'll be doing

During the service interruption, we'll be performing a failover from the primary location to a secondary server in New York. This allows us to patch the former primary SQL Server and apply Windows updates to the server. By putting the sites in a read-only state, we reduce the chance of data loss and the entire process becomes faster.

We expect that the site will be in a read-only state for less than 30 minutes. Once we've done the failover, and everything seems to be up and running, we'll take the sites out of read-only.

### Questions or concerns?

Please post a comment or answer below; I'll do my best to address any concerns between now and the maintenance window.

Comment: Is this the continuation of the previous fail-overs?

Comment: @Luuklag Sort of, we're going to patch the servers but we will also be gathering more data for Microsoft.

Comment: It's funny that stackoverflow uses windows server